# Exception while reading an empty table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception, sqlite

Iam trying to read data from a table.
Initially it is empty. If i tried to read at that time it will cause an exception.
My code is given Below

```
-(NSMutableArray *) selectDataFrom:(NSString *) tableName
{   
    NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM '%@' ",tableName];  
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2( dataBase, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"INSIDE IF");                    
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            NSLog(@"INSIDE WHILE");         
            // my code
        }
    }
    return allData; 
}
```

The first NSLog("INDISE IF"); is printed.
But the second one is not printing.

Mention some books to learn sqlite3 statements of iPhone [ eg: sqlite_prepare_v2();] **not SQL**

**[ Sorry for my poor English]**

THIS IS THE FULL CODE

```
-(NSMutableArray *) selectDataFrom:(NSString *) tableName
{

    allData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM '%@' ",tableName];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2( dataBase, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {       


        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            NSLog(@"REACHED 1");            
            myProgram = [[Programs alloc] init];    

            char *date  = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            myProgram.nss_Date = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:date];            

            char *type  = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
            myProgram.nss_Type = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:type];

            [nsma_allDonorsMA addObject:d_OneDonor];        
        }
    }
    else {
        //      NSLog(@"failed to select data");

    }
    return allData;
}
```

Comment: This is the exception:                                                    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: What happens where you typed `// my code`? Since you’re not doing anything with an `NSMutableArray` in the code you showed we can’t say what you did wrong with it.

Comment: Sven,  The problem is when selecting an empty table. When i tried to read a non-empty table , there is no problem.

Comment: Thank you Sven. for your precious time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabled breakpoints on exceptions and run your app in the debugger. It will show you exactly where you are calling `objectAtIndex:`. (It is *not* in the above code)

Comment: Thank you St3fan, I did as you told. I found the reason for exception.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your [sqlite3_finalize()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) ??

You should release sqlite3_stmt structure in your sqlite3_prepare_v2 block, as following.

```
sqlite3_stmt *sql_stmt; 
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(...) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    ....

    sqlite3_finalize(sql_stmt);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Toro for your reply